# CakePHP subdomains with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I've used the following rules in my htaccess file in other applications to redirect users from a folder to a subdomain but load the content from that folder when accessing that subdomain.

```
# REWRITE SUBDOMAIN TO FOLDER
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.cameron\.com$
RewriteRule !^admin/? admin%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

# REWRITE FOLDER TO SUBDOMAIN
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/admin/([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://admin.cameron.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

So if I go to: `http://cameron.com/admin` I end up on `http://admin.cameron.com/`

But the content is loaded from `http://cameron.com/admin`

However this doesn't work for CakePHP 2.x because of its rewriting apparently...

In my htaccess file in `/app/webroot` I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # CAKEPHP RULES
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

    # REWRITE SUBDOMAIN TO FOLDER
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.cameron\.com$
    RewriteRule !^admin/? admin%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

    # REWRITE FOLDER TO SUBDOMAIN
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/admin/([^\s]*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://admin.cameron.com/%1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

If I go to: `http://cameron.com/admin` it just tries to load the AdminController and doesn't redirect you, and if I go to: `http://admin.cameron.com/` I just get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Any ideas on how to get this working for CakePHP?

Comment: If I'm right, do you just want to change the url to point to that of the subdomain?

Comment: Try adding this statement RewriteBase /app/webroot after the RewriteEngine On in your webroot .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP and almost any other PHP framework parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in order to route your request to particular controller

more info here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6/lib/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php#L230 ,

so you simply need to have the SAME request URI parameters for your redirect to get app working.

For your old location it was "/admin", for new location it should be the same, but you do not want to pass it, so it is better to change the task like this:

"When you go to admin.site.com you will be redirected to site.com/admin".

This can be done simply like this:

`RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.example\.com http://example.com/$1`

It is not a working example of rule because you also need to rewrite subdomain's request URI to to get everything working and it depends on your requirements, but can be smth like this:

`RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.example\.com(.*) http://example.com/$1/$2`

**UPD: real example**

```
$ cat app/webroot/.htaccess 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.example.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/admin/$1 [P,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have a full htaccess example that works? As my rules worked prior to being used with CakePHP which is where the issue is.

Comment: $ cat app/webroot/.htaccess



`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.cake.local
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cake.local/admin/$1 [P,L,NC]
</IfModule>`

Comment: I've updated an answer too with more readable version of previous comment

Answer (score 0):

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  #standard cake htaccess stuff
  ...

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^profile\.thechatfun\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thechatfun.com/users/profile/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^chat\.thechatfun\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thechatfun.com/chats/index/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```