# CakePHP 3 how to correctly set .htaccess for subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I have CakePHP project placed on the subdomain on multihosting with the following path to the app directory.

```
/www/domains/sub.domain.com
```

The problem is that all links in the app are changed to:

```
https://sub.domain.com/domains/sub.domain.com/health-check
```

instead of the:

```
https://sub.domain.com/health-check
```

CakePHP .htacess has the following format:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried to set some rewrite rules but without the luck.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: When you say "CakePHP project...with the following path to the app directory", can you be a little more clear about exactly what the "app directory" is? Cake3 doesn't really have an "app directory", so I'm wondering where you've put things like the `src`, `vendor` and `webroot` directories, or their contents, relative to this structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP subdomains with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002125/cakephp-subdomains-with-htaccess)

Comment: Directories src, vendor, webroot are  situated in /www/domains/sub.domain.com/

Comment: Can you try adding `RewriteBase /www/domains/sub.domain.com` below `RewriteEngine on`?